# Flickering div when using CSS transform on hover

Tags: html, css, hover, transform

I'm making a `div` on top of the tweet (and also the Facebook like) button. I want it to move up as soon as I hover above the `div` (button) so you can actually press the real tweet button. I've tried the following.

HTML:

```
<div class="tweet-bttn">Tweet</div>         
<div class="tweet-widget">
    <a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button">Tweet</a>
    <script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+'://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js';fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document, 'script', 'twitter-wjs');</script>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.tweet-bttn{
    position: relative;
    top: -30px;
    left: -10px;
    display:block;
    opacity: 1;
    width: 80px;
    padding: 10px 12px;
    margin:0px;
    z-index:3;}

.tweet-bttn:hover{
    -webkit-animation-name: UpTweet;
    -moz-animation-name: UpTweet;
    -o-animation-name: UpTweet;
    animation-name: UpTweet;
    -webkit-animation-duration:.5s;
    -moz-animation-duration:.5s;
    animation-duration:.5s;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 200ms ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: -moz-transform 200ms ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: -o-transform 200ms ease-in-out;
    transition: transform 200ms ease-in-out;}

@-webkit-keyframes UpTweet {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
    }   
    80% {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(-55px);
    }
    90% {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(-47px);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(-50px);
    }
    ... and all other browser pre-fixes.
}
```

I'm not sure what's going wrong. It looks like that as soon as I hover, it moves, but if I move the cursor one more pixel, it has to do a new calculation which causes the flickering.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know why you need animations for this when you can simply achieve the above using `transitions`

The trick is to move the child element on parent hover

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/VKwjD/)

```
div {
    margin: 100px;
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid #aaa;
    height: 30px;
}

div span {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    width: 100px;
    background: #fff;
    top: 0;
    -moz-transition: all 1s;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s;
    transition: all 1s;
}

div span:nth-of-type(1) {
/* Just to be sure the element stays above the 
   content to be revealed */
    z-index: 1;
}

div:hover span:nth-of-type(1) { /* Move span on parent hover */
    top: -40px;
}
```

---

Explanation: Firstly we wrap `span`'s inside a `div` element which is `position: relative;`
 and later we use `transition` on `span` which will help us to smooth the flow of the `animation`, now we use `position: absolute;` with `left: 0;`, this will stack elements on one another, than we use `z-index` to make sure the first element overlays the second.

Now at last, we move the first `span`, we select that by using `nth-of-type(1)`, which is nothing but first child of it's kind which is nested inside `div`, and we assign `top: -40px;` which will transit when the parent `div` is hovered.

Comment: Well, I didn't know this but it looks like its working like a charm. Thank you so very much!!

Comment: @EmielJanson You welcome, and if you don't know than try to learn about that :) though I will edit my answer to explain, sorry I missed that

Comment: @EmielJanson explained :)

Comment: Thanks a lot! It all started to make sense. I've played around a little. :)