# CSS Card Flip Glitch (Padding? Margin?)

Tags: html, css, css-animations, card-flip

I'm trying to create an interactive calendar. I've added a neat CSS Card Flip animation [(tutorial here)](http://davidwalsh.name/css-flip) to flip a calendar date and display more information on the back of the card.

Problem if you hover your mouse over the dates, for some reason there is a small, highlighted white bar at the top of the box. I can't seem to figure out how to fix it (red arrow in the image below indicates the problem).

[image: Problem indicated by the red arrow]

Here is a CodePen and HTML illustrating the problem. I'm not sure what part of the CSS code is causing the problem.
http://codepen.io/ipiyale/pen/Athfd?editors=110

```
<div class="col-lg-2 col-md-4 col-xs-6 thumb flip-container">
    <div class="thumbnail flipper">
        <div class="day front"><h2>1</h2></div>
        <div class="activity back">
            <p>Afternoon Activity</p>
            <p>Evening Activity</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`backface-visibility`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/backface-visibility) appears to help.

```
/* flip the pane when hovered */
.flip-container:hover .flipper, .flip-container.hover .flipper {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}
```

via [How to fix flicker when using Webkit transforms & transitions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2975217/how-to-fix-flicker-when-using-webkit-transforms-transitions)

Another solution, involves moving the elements that are causing the flickering. See [Flickering div when using CSS transform on hover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18845136/flickering-div-when-using-css-transform-on-hover).

Comment: This does fix the problem when the card is flipped, but the padding issue still appears for a split second during the rollover.

Comment: Yes, it looks like the padding is causing the overall issue. I'll leave my answer for other folks where this solution may be applicable.

Comment: Definitely interesting! Not a style I am familiar with so I'll need to look into it. :)

Comment: Thanks so much for answering this! This together with @JSuar's padding suggestion did the trick. Thank you both for helping out!

Answer (score 2):

The issue is caused by the `padding: 4px;` on the `.thumbnail` class.

`.thumbnail` is a built-in Bootstrap style. Your best bet would be to override the padding in your own CSS.

To see this, open the browser inspector (in Chrome, right-click and choose "Inspect Element") and you'll see that the `.thumbnail` class has a padding of 4px. If you uncheck that style, you'll see that the problem goes away.

I've posted a fork of your demo here. You can see near the bottom of your CSS where I added an override for padding: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eHKma

```
.thumbnail {
    padding: 0;
}
```